# Help in multiple sigma question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

> Find the value of $\displaystyle \underset{(i \ne j \ne k)}{\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{3^i 3^j 3^k}}$.

How to solve questions containing multiple sigma like this question? 
How can i solve such questions please help. 
This is question is just in general actually i want help to encounter questions with multiple sigma.

It's answer is $81/208$

Comment: The meaning of $i\neq j \neq k$ is not clear. It could mean $i\neq j$ and $j \neq k$ or that $i,j,k$ are all distinct.

Comment: **HINT:** When dealing with $k$, treat $i,j$ as constants. You get $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{3^i}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{3^j}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{3^k}\right)\right)$$ Now use geometric series.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire No like this answer will not come

Comment: @RafaelNadal Have you even tried solving the expression? Do you know the formula for an infinite geometric series?

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the inclusion-exclusion principle:
$$\displaystyle \underset{(i \ne j \ne k)}{\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{3^i 3^j 3^k}}=\cdots=\left(\frac32\right)^3-3\cdot\left(\frac32\cdot \frac98\right)+2\cdot\frac{27}{26}=\frac{81}{208}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant $i \neq j, j \neq k, k \neq i$. One of such case is $i < j < k$. In that case,
$$ \sum^\infty_{i=0} \sum^\infty_{j=i+1} \sum^\infty_{k=j+1} \frac{1}{3^i 3^j 3^k}$$
is a part of given expression.
Now, how much there are such cases?